# Изменить статус главного окна Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

При запуске приложения пользователю показывается форма с авторизацией. Она есть главной формой в проекте. В зависимости от статуса пользователя открывается форма для простого пользователя или форма для администратора, при этом главную форму хочу закрывать. Можно ли как-нибудь динамически присвоить статус главной формы проекта другой форме, чтобы при закрытии главной формы, заданной в Main(), можно было продолжать работать с другой формой проекта.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно изменить главную форму через [`ApplicationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.mainform(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static class Program
{
    public static ApplicationContext Context { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Context = new ApplicationContext(new Form1());
        Application.Run(Context);
    }
}
```

в форме логина:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.Context.MainForm = new Form2();

    this.Close();

    // покажет вторую форму и оставит приложение живым до ее закрытия
    Program.Context.MainForm.Show(); 
}
```